# is there any free tab viewer for GuitarPro files?

Tags: guitar, practice, software

I just want to view not edit tabs and I think paying 60 bucks to listen/edit is too much.

Comment: I think this is kind of sad. $60 is really not a lot of money for software, especially something as useful as guitar pro (even if you're not editing). Particularly when you compare it to how much you might spend on guitars, amps, pedals. I think it's important to support companies making useful products so that they can continue doing it! <end soap box>

Answer (score 13):

There's also [TuxGuitar](http://tuxguitar.herac.com.ar/). It's not as good as Guitar Pro, but should be enough for your needs.

Comment: This was my choice as soon as I moved over to Linux, back a uni.

Answer (score 4):

Dguitar is released under GNU/GPL (is not an editor YET) but it display, plays guitar pro 3 and 4

main page is here
http://dguitar.sourceforge.net/

installation steps are here
http://dguitar.sourceforge.net/en/index.html

Answer (score 3):

My favorite is [TabToolkit](http://www.agilepartners.com/apps/tabtoolkit/) for iPad. If you have an iPad, it is $10 well spent.

I know the title says free, but in the questions you said that $60 is too much. I agree, but I don't think $10 is too much.

Comment: I only have an iPhone, but TabToolkit was worth $10 on that platform, too. I love being able to carry a bunch of tabs in my pocket! Now that I have GP also, they work very well as complements to each other.

Comment: Guitar Pro also exist for iPad / iPhone / android, for less than that ($6)

Answer (score 2):

#### Free/Open-Source (GPL) Guitar Pro Tabs Viewer:

- [**DGuitar**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dguitar/)
- [**Phone Guitar Tab**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/phone-guitar-tab/9wzdncrfhxmn) *(For Windows Phones)*
- [**TuxGuitar**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tuxguitar/)
- [**Tab Star**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tab-star-free-guitar-pro-tabs/id853572354?mt=8) *(iPhone and iPad)*
- [**Guitar Tab Viewer**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.lequem.sgptviewer&hl=en) *(Android Devices)*
- [**Guitar Tab Player**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=guitartab.player&hl=en) *(Android Devices)*
- [**GuitarTab**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gt.guitarTab&hl=en) *(Android Devices)*

#### Guitar Pro Tabs Online Viewer:

- [**DBoards**](https://www.dboards.com/guitar-pro-viewer)
- [**Web Tab Player**](http://www.webtabplayer.com/)
- [**Learn By Cam**](https://www.learnbycam.com/learn/tools/guitarproviewer.aspx)

*and many more...*

Answer (score 1):

### [Songsterr](http://www.songsterr.com/)

is an online Guitar Pro playing site. It's a "freemium" model, where the free version gets you limited functionality (from memory):

- No turning individual parts up / down / off / on.
- No printing

If you subscribe then those limitations are lifted, but...a year of it costs more than Guitar Pro! I just got it for the purposes you describe - and as a backup band! I thought it was worth much more than the $50 I paid for it. Check Amazon, Guitar Center, etc.. for discounted pricing.

Answer (score 1):

There are Chrome extensions to view guitar pro tabs directly online: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/guitar%20pro%20viewer?hl=es&_ac=0

Answer (score 0):

If a web-based reader is OK for you, try [Soundslice](https://www.soundslice.com/). You'll have to create a [free account](https://www.soundslice.com/teachers/), but it lets you view and play back Guitar Pro files from versions 3 and up. The free version is limited to 20 files/scores. The import/rendering is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

TEFview for IOS or for Android open, play and print as pdf all GP files (an many other file types). TEFview is freeware.